# How to Encrypt/Decrypt data in Angular and Java - CryptoJS

Tags: java, angular, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I found this code

```
package com.sumant.springboot.learning.springcloudgateway;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EncryptDecryptHelper {

    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "Thisisatestkeyfortesting";


    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt){
        return encrypt(strToEncrypt, SECRET_KEY);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt){
        return decrypt(strToDecrypt, SECRET_KEY);
    }

    public static void setKey(String myKey)
    {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
//          System.out.println(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");          
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String key = "Thisisatestkeyfortesting";

        //language=JSON
        String data = "{\"title\": \"TestTitle1\",\"author\": \"TestAuthor1\"}";

        System.out.println("Original String: " + data);

        String encryptedString = EncryptDecryptHelper.encrypt(data, key);

        System.out.println("Encrypted String: " + encryptedString);

        String decryptedString = EncryptDecryptHelper.decrypt(encryptedString, key);

        System.out.println("Decrypted String: " + decryptedString);

    }
}
```

This generates encryption string

> Encrypted String:
> Qua63XoZnGDpvBYtmoEZipALDamRw6EvmB0oWLD+wgi80PzmMZw2WTX4CIP6R79+

How can I encrypt/decrypt in angular using crypto-js

The code to encrypt on angular side (using encrypt on both sides to confirm settings are ok)

```
 public message: string= "{\"title\": \"TestTitle1\",\"author\": \"TestAuthor1\"}";
  public password: string ="Thisisatestkeyfortesting";
  
  public decryptedMessage: string;


    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.password);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.password);
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(this.message, key, {
      keySize: 16,
      iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    console.log('Encrypted :' + encrypted);
```

> Encrypted
> :peUrphsVZzpQbi5GF8JWgQ3mWY0tGCE5m9VHM/dYibizS37hUarfHzoFXrKbJZsv

What is wrong in the above code ? why the encrypted text are different? Please suggest the fix

Main goal is to encrypt on angular and decrypt on java/spring , and vise versa

Comment: In the Java code the key is derived using SHA1 (which is insecure by the way, more secure is e.g. PBKDF2), while in the CryptoJS code the key is used directly. Also, ECB (which is also insecure, by the way) does not use an IV, so the IV does not need to be specified in the CryptoJS code.

Comment: Great. can you give me more details especially - "key is used directly.". In java I was not sure how to view secretKey

Comment: _Direct_ means that in the CryptoJS code the key is generated by merely UTF8 encoding the password. In order to generate the same key as in the Java code, the SHA1 hash of the password must be created and from this the first 16 bytes have to be used.

Comment: I can understand that bit, hence asked how can I view it , and use in angular. Hope my question is clear - need help on code

Comment: On the Java side the key is e.g. given by [`SecretKeySpec#getEncoded()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html#getEncoded()).

Comment: cool. I tried - String s = new String(secretKey.getEncoded(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); and I see gibberish characters. Would you be able to give an answer ?

Comment: You can't generally Utf8 encode a hash. Use a binary to text encoding like Base64 or hex. Note that the actual fix must happen in the CryptoJS code: Create the SHA1 hash of the password and use the first 16 bytes of it as key.

Comment: that is understandable and gets me my original question how. I did hex and got "cbaa254fde5a264de713989f68ec34fd" , I used this on Angular and the output hasn't changes at all

Comment: Your key is OK, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b8p1jva2/).

Comment: Thanks for the example.. I used "cbaa254fde5a264de713989f68ec34fd" , but the example genrates again - var key = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(hash.words.slice(0, 16 / 4));. Is it possible to use "cbaa254fde5a264de713989f68ec34fd" value by applying hex or something (than creating SHA1, wordarray)

Comment: The first 16 bytes of the SHA1 hash of `Thisisatestkeyfortesting` are hex encoded: `cb...fd`. The post on jsfiddle mimics the logic of the Java code and generates this key from the password. You can also directly convert `cb...fd` to a `WordArray`: `var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("cb...fd")`, s. [here](https://jsfiddle.net/91p4zmqw/), but usually the password and not the key is known.

Comment: How can we apply this to a service function whose return type is Observable<any>. We make REST call and we capture in Observable. How can we enc/dec in such scenario?

Comment: ok used pipe and map!

Comment: It seems the problems don't end. I used import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'; in angular service, and this is complaining - cannot find module crypto-js or its corresponding  type declaration
Scenario: Machine1 - Used npm install crypto-js, and works
Machine2  ; get latest from repository and errors - cannot find module crypto-js
Do I need to run npm install on machine 2? what if this doesn't work when I deploy on AppEngine.?